# Gekodriver added to path, but Selenium says otherwise

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm currently trying to learn how to use Selenium with Python, but no matter what code I run, I always get the same error. I did add geckodriver to my path (at least I think I did) so I'm not sure what's wrong

The error is as below :

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: Have you searched for a solution to your problem? There are many examples of how to do this, on this site as well as others. E.g., look at the "Related" questions on this page. In general you will find a solution faster if you search yourself, and only then if you don't find an answer should you ask here. And when you do ask, include your code. I.e., you say you added geckodriver to your path. How did you do that?

Comment: That should work. Again, how did you do that? What *exactly* did you enter, and where? How are you running your code? What code are you running, and how? The more information about your situation you provide, the more specific and useful our answers can be. And as I mentioned, you'll find solutions to your problem elsewhere here without waiting for people to respond to your question. For example, your question is a duplicate of this already answered one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest Geckodriver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

unzip it and put the geckodriver.exe file in C:\Python27 and than try to run, it will work.

Note if you are using selenium 3.x than please upgrade to latest(3.3.1) one as there are some issues in 3.0.x due to which you will not be able to see selenium typing anything in firefox browser.

Comment: It still gives the same error.

Comment: which OS you are using and which version of Firefox/selenium?